# running django project on a other machine, giving error

Tags: django

I would like to run my django project on a other machine.
When running python3 manage.py runserver i get the error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/homes/bvink/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 336, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I can access mysql on the this 'other' machine.
Can someone help me get the project running?

EDIT:
my database section in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'Bvink',
        'USER': 'bvink',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
        'HOST': 'mariadb',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I also get this error when i type python3 manage.py makemigrations, migrate and shell

Comment: What does your DATABASES setting look like? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: ofcourse, it's added

Comment: What happens if you change your ENGINE to 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', also do you have mysqlclient installed on this other machine?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes